# mysql syntax USING and ON on same query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT * 
FROM p USING profile p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN inter i ON p.inter_id = i.inter_id 
WHERE i.inter_id = 0;
```

is showing an error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'USING profile p LEFT OUTER JOIN inter i ON p.inter_id = i.inter'
>   at line 1

But

```
DELETE FROM p USING profile p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN inter i ON p.inter_id = i.inter_id 
WHERE i.inter_id = 0;
```

is working fine.

Comment: I replaced the select query as
 "SELECT * FROM profile p LEFT OUTER JOIN inter i ON p.inter_id = i.inter_id WHERE i.inter_id = 0;

Is this same?? any difference in logic??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used in the context of a `JOIN` operation `USING` keyword replaces `ON`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM profile p  
LEFT OUTER JOIN inter i USING(inter_id)
WHERE i.inter_id = 0;
```

This is just syntactic sugar for the 'classic' `ON` clause:

`ON p.inter_id = i.inter_id`

However, when `USING` keyword is used in the context of a `DELETE` operation is used as follows:

```
DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    FROM tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    USING table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
```

The above query expresses a *multi-table* `DELETE` operation:  only matching rows from the tables listed in the `FROM` clause (**before the USING clause**) are deleted.

**Reference:** [**DELETE Syntax**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html)

Comment: In other words, the first query is using incorrect syntax and the second is correct +1.

Comment: I replaced the select query as 

"SELECT * FROM profile p LEFT OUTER JOIN inter i ON p.inter_id = i.inter_id WHERE i.inter_id = 0; Is this same?? any difference in logic??

Comment: @Sruthy Yes, both queries are identical.